# Piping Recuperate e-mail in php Cpanel

Tags: php, email, pipe

I use CPANEL of o2switch with a rather limited access on it I can't install pear for example.

I want to make an e-mail piping so that the e-mails are redirected on a php script and I would like to get only the body and not all the poop which goes with and there is very little documentation...
[Screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaA3d.png)

```
     #!/usr/local/bin/php -c  /home/-/public_html/php.ini -q
<?php
// source : https://forums.cpanel.net/f5/email-forward-php-script-39083.html
// read from stdin
 $fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
 $email = "";
 while (!feof($fd)) {
$email .= fread($fd, 1024);
 }
   fclose($fd);

   // handle email
   $lines = explode("\n", $email);

  // empty vars
   $from = "";
    $subject = "";
    $headers = "";
    $message = "";
    $splittingheaders = true;

    for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if ($splittingheaders) {
    // this is a header
    $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";

    // look out for special headers
    if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
        $subject = $matches[1];
    }
    if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
        $from = $matches[1];
    }
} else {
    // not a header, but message
    $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
}

if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
    // empty line, header section has ended
    $splittingheaders = false;
   }
   }

 file_put_contents('/home/-/public_html/mail.txt',$message,LOCK_EX);

 $to = $from;
$sb = "PIPING";
$body = "$from - $subject - $message";
$headers = "From: x@mal.lu\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: REPLYTOADDRESS\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: RETURNPATHADDRESS\r\n";
mail($to, $sb, $body, $headers);

exit(0);
 
?>
```